# To run web camera in Java-Applet code

Tags: java

I want to access web camera through Java-Applet code...
Can u give me sample code & somewhat basic information about it.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question? Some code that you've tried? Something other than an open-ended request for code?
Also, you haven't accepted any answers to any of your other questions, so people will be less likely to help you until you do.

Answer (score 1):

Start with [JMF](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/). It's the Java Media Framework which offers you a (pretty low-level) API to access media (audio/video) related devices. I am not going to post code here since you put that much effort in the question yourself as well, but at the [Sun forums](http://www.google.com/search?q=jmf+webcam+site%3Aforums.sun.com) you can find a lot of code examples.